# Pivoting a Dataframe column transforming on a User ID Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have A Dataframe that looks like

```
+------+------------+------------------+
|UserID|Attribute   | Value            |
+------+------------+------------------+
|123   |  City      | San Francisco    |
|123   |  Lang      | English          |
|111   |  Lang      | French           |
|111   |  Age       | 23               |
|111   |  Gender    | Female           |
+------+------------+------------------+
```

So i have few distinct Attributes that can be null for some users (limited Attributes say 20 max)

I want to Convert this DF to

```
+-----+--------------+---------+-----+--------+
|User |City          | Lang    | Age | Gender |
+-----+--------------+---------+-----+--------+
|123  |San Francisco | English | NULL| NULL   |
|111  |          NULL| French  | 23  | Female |
+-----+--------------+---------+-----+--------+
```

I'm quite new to  Spark and Scala.

Comment: Is it worth adding an attempt at this? It is as risk of closure if it is just a set of requirements. If you can research the problem and try, that is often much appreciated.

Comment: @halfer i tried getting distinct of Attributes and defined a new Dataframe but that seems causing issues with mapping values into the desired columns

Comment: I don't know this technology, but that information, and the code you used, might be useful edited into the question. It is good to show that you have genuinely tried something, given that many people here do not even bother doing a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot` to get the desired output:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

df.groupBy("UserID")
  .pivot("Attribute")
  .agg(first("Value")).show()
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
+------+----+-------------+------+-------+
|UserID| Age|         City|Gender|   Lang|
+------+----+-------------+------+-------+
|   111|  23|         null|Female| French|
|   123|null|San Francisco|  null|English|
+------+----+-------------+------+-------+
```